# Misplaced Information on 2 PickerView

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I am using 2 Pickerview in my application. However their information will mix while using. For example: If I select 2.row in first  picker, then the system changes second pickers row into 2, and reverse does same.

My code is here:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    petArray = ["A","B","C","D"]

    feedTimeArray = ["1","2","3","4"]

}    

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView.tag == 1{
        return petArray.count
    }
    if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        return feedTimeArray.count
    }
    return 0
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return petArray[row]
    }
    if pickerView.tag == 2{
        return feedTimeArray[row]
    }
    return ""
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    selectedFeed = feedTimeArray[row]
    print(feedTimeArray[row])

    if selectedFeed == feedTimeArray[1] {
        //case 1
    }

    if selectedFeed == feedTimeArray[2] {
        //case 2
    }
    if selectedFeed == feedTimeArray[3] {
        //case 3
    }

    selectedPet = petArray[row]
    print(petArray[row]) }
```

**Example:**

I selected B
system changed second picker to 2

I selected 4
system changed first picker to D

Comment: You could also add a condition of checking the tag of the pickerview in didselectRow.

Comment: @Sneha Your and Zee's nswer solve the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `didSelectRow` method will be like this

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

 if pickerView.tag == 1
 {
    selectedFeed = feedTimeArray[row]
    print(feedTimeArray[row])

     if selectedFeed == feedTimeArray[1] {
     //case 1
     }

      if selectedFeed == feedTimeArray[2] {
      //case 2
     }
     if selectedFeed == feedTimeArray[3] {
     //case 3
     }
 }
 else if pickerView.tag == 2
 {
     selectedPet = petArray[row]
     print(petArray[row]) 
 }
 else
   {   }
}
```